# How to use my local database when developing an Openshift application?

Tags: database, configuration, openshift

I'm giving a try to the openshift platform but I don't get how to configure it to use my local database instance (mySql, postgres, mongodb...) when doing local testing

Should I use environment variables like OPENSHIFT__DB_HOST in my local machine?

Could I use maven profiles or something like that to use a different datasource depending on the environment?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a python/mongodb app.  I use

```
  import os
  if 'OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR' in os.environment :
       use Openshift's environment variables to setup database connection
  else
       use local DB or connect to OPenshift DB via port forward
```

To tell if I'm running on OPENSHIFT or my local PC system.

I have have two separate databases. My local small one for testing and the actual one on OPENSHIFT.

If on OPENSHIFT I just use their environment variables. If on my pc I just connect to my local development database.

You could also use port forward command 'rhc port -forward -a '  and then connect to your OPENSHIFT DB instance. You still would have to determine if your are local or OPENSHIFT to connect correctly.

Comment: Ok, I think I will use local environment variables to point to my local db. Thanks